# Remove extra line before first item of a list in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

When I create a bullet list in Sphinx by typing

```
Text before the listing

- Item 1
- Item 2

Text after the listing
```

it renders as follows:

[image: Output]

This behaviour is independent of the HTML theme (tried it with `'classic'` and `'sphinx_rtd_theme'`) and the markup language (be it ReStructuredText or Markdown with the [MyST](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) parser).

While it seems intentional that an extra line is added before the first item, I find it distracting.
Can I suppress the extra line with an option or an HTML/CSS modification?

Comment: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html#adding-custom-css-or-javascript-to-sphinx-documentation

Answer (score -1):

Sphinx supports [custom CSS styling](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html). If your CSS file is `_static/css/custom.css`, then you need to add its location to the *conf.py* file so that Sphinx finds it:

```
## conf.py

# These folders are copied to the documentation's HTML output
html_static_path = ['_static']

# These paths are either relative to html_static_path
# or fully qualified paths (eg. https://...)
html_css_files = [
    'css/custom.css',
]
```

To implement the desired formatting, put the following into the above-mentioned *custom.css* file:

```
p { margin: 0; }
ul { margin-top: 0; }
```

as described [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-remove-line-break-before-ul/1128/2).